# SQL Query for Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

There Is three table Master, Regular and Customer.

I'm saving ControlId in customer master for both Master and Regular. I want to get Profile from Master from the Customer Record.

By using below Query. I'm able to get MasterID from regular But I want Profile.

**Query**

```
select * from customer where refId='R000003'
    (select ControlId from regular where LicenseId='R000003')
```

**Result**

[image]

**Master Table**

[image]

**Regular Table**

[image]

My Query Is..

```
SELECT        Customer.CustomerId, Regular.LicenseId, Regular.ControlId, 
              Master.FullName, Master.profile
FROM          Customer INNER JOIN
              Regular ON Customer.RefId = Regular.LicenseId INNER JOIN
              Master ON Regular.ControlId = Master.MasterId                            
WHERE        (Customer.RefId = 'R000003')
```

But Its showing Regural's only I want Masters record also...

Comment: actually its not a inner query example. give me detail query that you required. like you want all record from customer where refid will meet to perticular masterid. if yes then reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? I'm not sure..

```
select regular.ControlId, master.profile
from regular r inner join master m ON (r.controlId = m.masterId)
where regular.LicenseId='R000003'
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an image of your data is not helpful. No one is going to type this in.
Paste the sample.

Comment: This should be a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that `RefId` and `LicenseId` refer to each other.  I think this is the query you want:

```
select c.*, m.profile
from customer c join
     regular r
     on c.refId = r.LicenseId join
     master m
     on r.controlId = m.MasterId;
```

I would advise you to fix your tables.  Join keys in different tables should have similar names, so you know they line up.  In fact, I almost always name my join keys as "Id", so this query would look more like like:

```
select c.*, m.profile
from customer c join
     regular r
     on c.CustomerId = r.CustomerId join
     master m
     on r.MasterId = m.MasterId;
```

Comment: There is different different method for each person. I Do believe to keep the same name but its old project. 

I'm Using this to get result...
@Gordon Linoff

SELECT        Customer.CustomerId, Regular.LicenseId, Regular.ControlId, 
     Master.FullName, Master.profile
FROM          Customer INNER JOIN
              Regular ON Customer.RefId = Regular.LicenseId INNER JOIN
              Master ON Regular.ControlId = Master.MasterId              
WHERE        (Customer.RefId = 'R000002')